# Separating negative numbers in a row

Tags: r

I have the following data set in a data frame Concatenation by square brackets :

```
2.152558660121547 -2.5288097630405373 -2.182210847353577 -2.260599309173921 -2.3735065848552206 -2.345873321122266  2.5951723062515732 -2.5666440436296636 -2.1922111573930803 -2.602270010387569 -2.3255753772614023 -11.435752398292653 -2.1471980792213876 -2.0147604731588857 -11.8567454621472 -2.4131938571914175
```

similar to

```
row 1 [-1 3 -4 -5 -6 ]
row 2 [-8 -3 -4  9 -6 ]
```

I would like to separate this into a single row I tried the following

```
  separate_rows(df, y, z, convert = TRUE)
```

Which seemed to work the only problem is the negative numbers are now positive. I would like to just remove the square brackets without the numbers turning positive.

Comment: Please edit your post to include `dput(A)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex to replace anything that isn't a space ( ), a numeric including a negative sign (`^-0-9`), you can write the following `gsub()` command:

```r
gsub("[^-0-9 ]", "",A)

# returns:
# "-1 3 -4 -5 -6"
```

This would remove the square brackets but also anything else that isn't a space, a negative sign and a numeric (0-9).

Because you didn't provide `A`, for completeness and reproducibility I assumed `A` to be:

```
A <- "[-1 3 -4 -5 -6]"
```

### Edit 1

Based on additional comments from OP, here's how you would use it in conjunction with the `separate_rows` function from `tidyr`.

1. First, our messy data:

```
df <- data.frame(z=c("[-1 -3]", "[3 -2 -4]", "[1 5]"))
print(df)

# returns:
#           z
# 1   [-1 -3]
# 2 [3 -2 -4]
# 3     [1 5]
```

2. Create our cleaning function, `clean()`:

```
clean <- function(x){gsub("[^-0-9 ]", "",x)}
```

3. Apply our cleaning function:

```
df$z <- lapply(df$z, clean)
```

4. Finally, bring in `separate_rows`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(df, z, sep=" ", convert=TRUE)
```

The output of that would be:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
      z
  <int>
1    -1
2    -3
3     3
4    -2
5    -4
6     1
7     5
```

Comment: Sorry I submitted the wrong question how about using separate rows function

Comment: @FalconX, would you mind posting a new question with a sample data? I'm happy to help there. Call `dput()` on your dataframe to dump your data out so we can help better!

Comment: @FalconX, I've edited my answer to reflect your new use-case. Hope this is good reference but if you need to provide even more information I suggest posting it as a new question with a reproducible data so I can give you more targeted help